# What are the advantages of binding a secondary to your left mouse button

Tags: diablo-iii

I see that more and more on the armory. Some people tell on forums that it's life changing.

What so different when you bind your secondary attack on left mouse button?

Comment: In case of Kridershot you would probably use Elemental Arrow as your primary skill. In other cases it's probably just because people find it easier or more comfortable

Comment: I still use a resource generator on my left click, just because it is easyer to spam when needed :p

Comment: I thinks its a matter of taste. However, with a calss liek Demon Hunter that generate ressource just by firing (hitting not required), having your generator on the left click allow you to genereate more easily since you don't have to hold shift to do it.

Comment: @WizLiz you mean right click?

Comment: yes i meant right click ;)

Answer (score 3):

One reason is that some people move their main attack to the right mouse button. This has the advantage that you are much less likely to activate things in the world by mistake - e.g. pick up grey items, activate cursed chests before you are ready, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because it does more damage and in some classes are used more often then the resource generator attack.

Maybe if you have enough resource regen that way you can really spam damage

Comment: I get that you can only use the spender, but what's the point in having it on left mouse button instead of right one. Or even inverting them.

Comment: I dont have clue, maybe it just a way to spam more or just a easier way, does the people that changed moved their resource generator attack to right click?
If not maybe they just increased their damage so much it was life changing

Comment: Yeah I saw some people who moved generator to right click

Answer (score 0):

You can map your keys to your liking.

In special cases, as mentioned before with Kridershot, or if you have high resource regen with WD/Wizz, you can completely remove the generator skill as it takes up one slot where you can put some utility skill for example.

I wonder why most people use the predefined keys in D3 as they are pretty awkward to use if you do not have large fist/palm.

For instance, move your potion from default 'Q' to the cedilla key (just before '1'), or move the whole skill keys one or two levels down, closer to shift to ease wrist pain.

Or just move stand still function to tab. There are hundred variations and since you can map the keys however you want, try it.

I had my key mapping changed almost 6 months in the game (with years before of playing D1 and D2), and it is just easier when you get used to it :)